# Ambari installation with the rest of hadoop ecosystems

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, bigdata, ambari

I am new in Hadoop and all related topics.
i have a cluster of 3 nodes (1 master and 2 Slaves) running hadoop on Ubuntu.
My question is, what should i install first, Ambari then hadoop then the rest of all ecosystems?
or should i install multi nodes cluster then a bunch of ecosystems then ambari?
Am really confused about this, waiting your novel answers guys.

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate SSH keys and copy between all servers. Make sure you can SSH in both directions on all machines
2. Install a supported database by Ambari, such as Postgres or MySQL
3. Install Ambari Server
4. Use a private key in the Ambari UI, which will provision Ambari Agents on all hosts
5. Use Amabri to install Hadoop stacks.

Most of this is documented in [Hortonworks documentation](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/installation.html)

Installing Ambari after installing any Hadoop tools won't work out very well because Amabri needs a specific folder structure and will have conflicts when trying to overwrite existing things